# How to add Config Transforms in Website Projects

Tags: web-config, config, web-config-transform

I am trying to add config transform in the Website Application in Visual Studio. Right now, it works only for Web Application projects. Is it possible to add them in WebSite Projects also? If so, how do we go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Under App_Data\PublishProfiles, right click on a publish profile (*.pubxml) and choose Add Config Transform.